# Forward Declaration of variables/classes in std namespace

Tags: c++, class, std, forward-declaration

I usually use forward declaration predominantly, if I have a class that does not need complete definition in .hpp file

Ex)

```
 //B.hpp

 namespace A_file {
   class A;
 }

 namespace B_file {

  class B {
   public:
        B();
   private:
        A *ptr_to_A;
  }
 }

 //B.cpp

 #include "A.hpp"
 using namespace A_file;

 namespace B_file {

   B(int value_) {
        *ptr_to_A = new A(value_);
   }

   int some_func() {
        ptr_to_A->some_func_in_A();
   }
 }
```

I write this kind of code. I think, it will save including the whole hpp again. (Feel free to comment, if you thing, this is not healthy)

Is there a way that I can do the same for objects/classes in std namespace?
If there is a way, is it okay or does it have side effects?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can forward declare your own classes in header files to save compilation time. But you can't for classes in namespace std. According to the C++11 standard, 17.6.4.2.1:

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or
> definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std
> unless otherwise specified.

Note that some of these classes are typedefs of class templates, so a simple forward declaration will not work. You can use `#include<iosfwd>` instead of `#include<iostream>` for example, but there are no similar headers with just forward declarations for `string`, `vector`, etc.

See [GotW #34, Forward Declarations](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/034.htm) for more information.

Comment: +1.  Predictably enough, the precedent set by `<iosfwd>` is also best practice: prefer to have an extra forward declaration header, included by the "normal" header to get compile-time checks for ongoing validity, and by clients who only need the forward declarations.  It should "live" and be maintained with the library whose code is forward declares, not the client code!  The exact reason given in the GotW above drives this: structures may become typedefs of templates, templates may add arguments etc..

Comment: Likely another reason for `<iosfwd>` existing while nothing for other headers is that a lot of `std` content is class templates that aren’t instantiated by the header. This means that you don’t pay for code generation that you don’t use. `<iostream>` on the other hand, instantiates `std::ostream` and other objects, which, if you only need to refer to the classes, e.g. to declare an `<<` operator, is wasteful. There are likely a few more headers for which this kind of argument could be made, but it was decided it’s not worth it.