# How to forward declare a C++ template class?

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration

Given a template class like the following:

```
template<typename Type, typename IDType=typename Type::IDType>
class Mappings
{
public:
    ...
    Type valueFor(const IDType& id) { // return value }
    ...
};
```

How can someone forward declare this class in a header file?

Answer (score 149):

This is how you would do it:

```
template<typename Type, typename IDType=typename Type::IDType>
class Mappings;

template<typename Type, typename IDType>
class Mappings
{
public:
    ...
    Type valueFor(const IDType& id) { // return value }
    ...
};
```

Note that the default is in the forward declaration and not in the actual definition.

Answer (score 20):

You ***can*** declare a templated class whose definition states the default arguments, but any time you reference the class you must include all its arguments until the definition is introduced.

eg. Let's use struct `Foo` without including it:

```
template <class>
struct Foo;

// Note that we *must* use the template here,
// even though in the definition it'll have a default.
template <class T> 
auto Func (Foo<T> foo)
{
    // do stuff with Foo before it's defined:
    return foo.Bar();
}

int Func (int n)
{
    return n;
}
```

We can then compile it *without* including the definition, eg.:

```
int main ()
{
    return Func(3);
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WW9aa43WE)

...***Or*** we can use it *after* including the definition, eg.:

```
template <class T = bool>
struct Foo
{
    T Bar () {return 9;}
};

// Now the compiler understands how to handle
// Foo with no template arguments
// (making use of its default argument)

int main ()
{
    return Func(Foo<>());
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Txr1jav3Y)

I haven't checked the standards, but this works on `clang`/`gcc` with `-std=c++98` up to `-std=c++17`, so if it's not officially a standard then it looks to be unofficially so.

---

Although in principal this should work for `namespace std`, and appears to in the examples I've checked (with many compilers), the standard states that it's undefined behaviour: According to the C++11 standard, 17.6.4.2.1:

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or
> definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std
> unless otherwise specified.

(I got this info from an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290176/8658157)).

Thanks to [Antonio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2436175/antonio) for pointing this out in the comments (and providing the link).

Comment: Maybe you forget empty angle brackets `Foo<> foo;`.

Comment: You shall not forward declare `std::vector` https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290176/2436175

Answer (score 8):

You can declare default arguments for a template only for the first declaration of the template. If you want allow users to forward declare a class template, you should provide a forwarding header. If you want to forward declare someone else's class template using defaults, you are out of luck!

Answer (score 2):

My answer complements the others as the solution I found actually mitigates the need for a template class forward declaration by creating a new type *when all parameters are known* (or provided as default) so that this new type, that you can forward declare, is not a template anymore:

```cpp
template<typename Type=MyDefault, typename IDType=typename Type::IDType>
class MappingsGeneric
{
...
};

class Mappings : public MappingsGeneric<> {};
```

You can then `class Mappings;`. I know that this solution doesn't apply everywhere but it did in my use case as I only used templates for high-performance dependency injection for non-virtual methods in a unit test context.