# Class is not a class template

Tags: c++, oop, templates

i get the error : class is not a class template .Any idea why?

```
template<class T>
class nod{
          friend class lista<T>;
protected:
          T info;
          nod<T> *urm,*prec;
        };
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`lista` is not known yet at this point in the code. So of course the compiler doesn't think it's a template class. You need to forward declare it with its template arguments. See also: [How to forward declare a C++ template class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848451/how-to-forward-declare-a-c-template-class)