# How to use a QMap in an interface

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

I'm trying to use a QMap in my class, but I get the error:

```
/* path */.h:18: error: template argument required for ‘class QMap’
 class QMap;
       ^~~~
```

**The implementation**

```
class QMap;

class MappingInterface
{

public:
    virtual ~MappingInterface() {}

    virtual QMap<QString, QString> itemsMap() const = 0;
};

#define MappingInterface_iid "com.myapp.MappingInterface"

    Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(MappingInterface, MappingInterface_iid)
```

How can I use a QMap inside a class?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why the forward declaration of `class QMap`?

Comment: The error is quite clear: There is no *class* `QMap`, only a class *template*.

Comment: How do you use QMap outside of a class? You would get the same error

Comment: I want to use it inside an interface (`MappingInterface` as shown in my question) @tobi303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QMap is a template and you can't just type `class QMap` instead of the header!
The short class prototype can be used for pointers only, for objects and the references you must include the header of the full class declaration!

You must include QMap's header:

```
#include <QMap>
#include <QString>

class MappingInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~MappingInterface() {}
    virtual QMap<QString, QString> itemsMap() const = 0;
};

#define MappingInterface_iid "com.myapp.MappingInterface"

Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE(MappingInterface, MappingInterface_iid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wohlstand's answer is not accurate, you can forward declare template classes.
With QMap you would do it like this:

```
 template <class Key, class T> class QMap;
```

you can indent it a bit if you prefer of course

```
template <class Key, class T> 
class QMap;
```

check these answers for more info about this

[How to forward declare a C++ template class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848451/how-to-forward-declare-a-c-template-class/13848492)

[When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)