# Declaring class type variable from other class gives C2143 error (missing ';' before '*" )

Tags: c++

I am coding general tree with C++ which expresses each node as class variable TreeNode, and each node's children (which can be more than 2) is expressed as TreeNodeList, which is the linked list of TreeNodes.

Here is the code that I've been working on so far.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename E>
class TreeNode {
    private:
    TreeNode* parent;
    TreeNodeList* children; // This line gives C2143 Error, missing ';' before '*'
    TreeNode* next;
    E data;
public:
    friend class TreeNodeList;
    TreeNode() {}
    TreeNode(E& data) {this->data = data;}
    void setParent(TreeNode<E> &p) {parent = &p;}
    void setData(E& data) { this->data = data; }
    void setNext(TreeNode<E>& n) { next = &n; }
    void addChild(TreeNode<E>& ch) {
        children.add(ch);
        ch.setParent(this);
    }
    TreeNode<E>* getChildren() const { return children; }
    TreeNode<E>* getNext() const { return next; }
    TreeNode<E>* getParent() const { return parent; }
    const E& getData() const { return data; }
};

template <typename E>
class TreeNodeList {
private:
    TreeNode* head;
    TreeNode* last;
    int size;
public:
    TreeNodeList() : head(NULL), last(NULL) { head = last; size = 0; }
    ~TreeNodeList() {
        while (!empty()) {
            removeFront();
        }
    }
    const bool empty() const {
        return size = 0;
    }
    void removeFront() {
        if (empty()) {
            return; //can't remove empty list
        }
        else {
            TreeNode<E>* old = head;
            head = head->getNext();
            delete old;
        }
    }
    void add(TreeNode<E>& p) {
        last->setNext(p);
        last = last->getNext();
    }
    void print() {
        TreeNode<E>* p = head;
        while (p != NULL) {
            cout << p->getData() << " ";
            p = p->getNext();
        }
    }
};
```

The line which I wrote "TreeNodeList* children" keeps giving me C2143 error, which says missing ';' before '*'. I can't understand this because declaring class type variable from other class looks completely fine to me.
Do declaring class type variable from other class gives this kind of error? I am stuck here so please help me to solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848451/how-to-forward-declare-a-c-template-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems with that line:

First: `TreeNodeList` is not declared yet. You can solve this by forward-declaring it:

```
class TreeNodeList;

template <typename E>
class TreeNode {
```

However, this won't work for you because:

Second: `TreeNodeList` is a template. So you need to specify the template parameter when using it (and forward-declare it as a template). You can fix the declaration of `children` as follows:

```
template<typename E>
class TreeNodeList;

template <typename E>
class TreeNode {
private:
    TreeNode* parent;
    TreeNodeList<E>* children;
```

Note how the declaration of `children` differs from yours.