# Overloading Iostream C++

Tags: c++, overloading, iostream

I'm writing a header only matrix3x3 implementation which I want to be independent and not relying on other headers except for a vector3 header which i also wrote.

Currently, I want it to overload ostream << operator but I don't want to include the *iostream* in it.

Is it possible to make the overloading optional and work if *ostream* is included, and if its not included to have all the rest work fine just without the overload?

I thought about the possibility of checking if the *ostream* header is included but it has a major flaw because it would not work correctly if *iostream* was included after the matrix3x3 header.

Edit:
I've replaced *iostream* with *ostream* as i think it created a bit of confusion regarding the point of the question.

Comment: Use a forward declaration for the `std::iostream` class?

Comment: I might not understand what forward declaration is about completely but wouldn't that mean that matrix3x3 header would have to relly on the fact that iostream exists?

Comment: `<iostream>` is not the header where [std::ostream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ostream) exists.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'll be honest, I can see why someone would make that assumption.

Comment: This is a rather interesting question IMHO. I read it as "Can I overload operator of a forward declared class?".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My bad, still i don't see how that helps with the problem or am i missing something?

Comment: @Selvidian Sorry, I missed you need a forward declaration for `std::ostream` like `template<typename T> class std::basic_ostream<T>;  using std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>;`

Comment: @user0042 I believe im on the right path now, thank you very much!

Comment: @user0042: Isn't that undefined behaviour? I don't think you are allowed to forward-declare standard-library classes. And for IO streams, there's `<iosfwd>`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Is it? May be I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [`<iosfwd>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iosfwd)?

Example:

```
#include <iosfwd>

class Example
{
public:
    Example(int i) : i(i) {}
private:
    int i;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Example const& example);
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Example e(123);
    std::cout << e << '\n';
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Example const& example)
{
    os << example.i;
    return os;
}
```

Note that you **cannot** safely forward-declare standard classes in your own code. Related questions:

- [Forward declare an STL container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307343/forward-declare-an-stl-container)
- [Forward Declaration of variables/classes in std namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289766/forward-declaration-of-variables-classes-in-std-namespace)

Comment: Still this has me #include something in my matrix3x3 header.
I'm trying to find an answer to the problem which does not require including anything and i believe what  
@user0042  proposed in the comments will do the trick.

Comment: @Selvidian: If you don't want to "`#include` something", then you are using the wrong language. `<iosfwd>` is made for your use case. Use it.

Comment: @Selvidian: What @user0042 proposed accomplishes nothing (because `<iosfwd>` does exactly the same thing) and possibly breaks something (because it's not allowed to forward-declare standard classes yourself).

Comment: Understood, it seems like my question has been answered. Thank you