# Including header or prototype of std::object

Tags: c++

I have a function which returns a type `std::istringstream` inside one of my classes. To avoid `#include <sstream>` in my header file, I wrote the prototype `class istringstream;` at the top of my header file and wrote the return type as `istringstream`. When defining the function in my cpp file, I wrote the return type as `std::istringstream`.

I now have ambiguity issues where I am unable to use `istringstream` without declaring it as `std::istringstream`, although I have `using std::istringstream`.

What is the best practice here? I had always learned to declare prototypes instead of including the full header when possible.

Here is an example for clarity:

example.h

```
class istringstream;

istringstream myFunction();
```

example.cpp

```
#include "example.h"
using std::istringstream;

std::istringstream myFunction(){} // istringstream is ambiguous
```

Update:

Answered in comments -> it is not recommended to forward declare and is in fact undefined behavior.

Comment: You can not make C++ standard library classes opaque so what you are trying to do seems pointless.

Comment: I'd just always learned to avoid including headers when possible and declaring prototypes instead @ÖöTiib . Is that not possible here?

Comment: `class istringstream;` is not a prototype, it is a forward declaration. It appears to be for something in the global namespace that you are promising to write, not for std::istringstream.

Comment: Is there any way to declare prototypes for `std::object` ? @AviBerger

Comment: It is advised opposite, include always all standard library headers that you use. Besides std::istringstream is not class but typedef of instantiation of std::basic_istringstream template.

Comment: C++ Standard prohibits forward declaration of anything in the `std` namespace, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290176/767632). So while it may work on a compiler of your choice, it may break at a whim. Or not.

Comment: @user18348324 — there is no `std::object`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I used `object` as a placeholder for ... any object.